# Is it possible to remove dom node from detached dom tree using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do:

```
$domTree = $('<div class="container"><div class="first">first</div><div class="second">second</div></div>')
$domTree.remove('.first')
$dom.html() // Should contain second div only
```

What I get: both first and second divs are present.

What I'm doing wrong? What's the right approach?

Comment: I think that `$dom.html();` is executing before `$domTree.move();` has finished. You can test this by wrapping the latter function in `setTimeout();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can , use `find` to get the element and `remove` to remove it, [end](https://api.jquery.com/end/) is used to return back the container

```
$domTree = $('<div class="container"><div class="first">first</div><div class="second">second</div></div>').find('.first').remove().end();
$domTree.html();
```

```js
$domTree = $('<div class="container"><div class="first">first</div><div class="second">second</div></div>').find('.first').remove().end();
    console.log($domTree[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what is the use of `end ` here

Comment: This doesnt get you back to the `#container` though! It logs just the `.second` div.

Comment: It works. And it doesn't if you skip `end`. Hm. Why?

Comment: @Jamiec yes it does

Comment: @FakeFish you are using find so the element currently selected is the `.first` to get back to the container you use end

Comment: @Jamiec html() returns the html of the container that is why it didn't returned in the first place